# db2 stored procedure if else variable comparison

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to compare a variable in db 2 sp using like, however it always goes to the else part of the statement, can someone correct the syntax here..here is the part of the code

```
do
  IF(@variable like '%abc') THEN
set @anotherVariable='abc';
  ELSEIF (@variable like '%def') THEN
set @anotherVariable='def';
  ELSEIF (@variable like '%def') THEN
set @anotherVariable='def';
  ELSE
set @anotherVariable='xyz';
  END IF;
END FOR;
```

This code is part of a cursor, query always returns 1 value, however my comparison is not working(incorrect syntax?), it always goes to the last else as if it never was able to match. I know that value is there but its not comparing in this  manner...Thanks

Comment: What are some sample values of the variable? (including any spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you writing  SQL-PL code? Because variables are referenced directly by its name, not preceded by the '@' sign.

Another thing is that you are using the like operator outside a query. 'Like' is not a function, it is a predicate: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000751.html

Instead, you can use a 'case' in the select and then return the corresponding value. In that way you do not need to do an 'if-else': http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023458.html

Comment: Yes, I changed the query and used case statement instead...I had thought of this earlier but for some reason was stuck in the cursor mindset..Thanks